# Aptana changing all <h1> to some snippet?

Tags: aptana

I'm writing a php file, and whenever I start to type

```
<h1>
```

I get this "snippet" of sorts,

```
// 
//  aptanavfs254116982902025803overrides.inc
//  wordpress
//  
//  Created by Mike on 2011-08-15.
//  Copyright 2011 Mike. All rights reserved.
//
```

What is this? I guess snippet is the wrong term. Template seems to be the wrong term. Googling doesn't seem to reveal people with this similar problem.

(Using Aptana Studio 3)

EDIT: I've found that it's somehow a shortcut for "Insert Comment Header" but there is still nothing that guides me to a preference to change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Insert Comment Header" command is actually contributed by the source ruble.  It looks like the trigger keyword is "head", so if you start typing 'he' it will show this command as a suggestion.  If you would like to remove this, you would need to edit the ruble.

Go to Commands > Source > Edit this ruble, to open the ruble. Then under the commands folder, open the insert_source_header.rb.  You can then edi the "cmd.trigger" field to something else so it doesn't get triggered when you type "head".

For more information on editing rubles, you can always go to

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+an+existing+Ruble

(There should be information there to do more advanced things with rubles)

Comment: Thank you, this answered it. I hadn't seen this anywhere online, but I believe my Aptana Studio was an upgrade from an Eclipse install, so more of a rare case. Thanks again.